# How to prevent [view source] link when creating documentation using yard?

Tags: ruby, rake, yard

I am using yard to generate project documentation, but i don't want to display the [view source] link in the documentation, i have dived into the yard official guides but still don't get the solution.

Anything ideas? Thanks.

Comment: same problem here. did you find a solution?

Comment: I have been looking at their documentation as well and haven't found an answer :(

Answer (score 6):

I might be a little late but you can trivially customize the default template by removing the "source" section from the method_details partial. You can do so by creating the file "my_template/default/method_details/setup.rb" in the root of your project with the contents:

```
def init
  super
  sections.first.delete(:source)
end
```

Then you can call YARD with your custom template modifications:

```
$ yardoc -p my_template
```

Comment: @TheLindyHop I had the same question, but what worked for me was doing `mkdir -p .yard_templates/no_source/default/method_details` in the root of the project (but it could be anywhere helpful) then adding the file `setup.rb` to method_details as above, then running yard via `yardoc -o docs/no_source -p .yard_templates/no_source`.

Comment: Would this way be preferred over this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/yardoc/-HH48h-aifs
?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a direct way to do this in yard, but you can try running the following on the generated yard documentation folder:

```
require "find"

Find.find(".") do |file|
  if file.match(/\.html$/)
    puts "Filtering #{file}"
    content = File.read(file)
    no_source_content = content.gsub(/<table class="source_code".*?<\/table>/m, "")
    File.open(file, "w") { |io| io.write no_source_content }
  end
end

unless File.read("css/common.css").match(/Hide source links/)
  File.open("css/common.css", "a+") { |io| io.write("\n/* Hide source links */\n.toggleSource { display:none }") }
end
```

https://gist.github.com/1306615

Answer (score 0):

Currently i just use javascript to remove the source html:

```
$('.showSource').remove();
```